# Animate SVG attribute fill to have a gradient fill after animation

Tags: animation, svg

I have a SVG rect which I have configured to animate, to change color,at user click.

```
<linearGradient id="linearGradient850" x1="-28.773" x2="119.68" y1="53.936" y2="50.846" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color=${this.theme.secondaryColor} offset="0"></stop>
        <stop stop-color=${this.theme.primaryColor} offset="1"></stop>
</linearGradient>

 <rect id="toggle-button-base" x="3.6e-07" y="1.3968" width="167.37" height="83.685997" rx="39.641998" ry="41.841999" fill="${this.theme.input_bg_color}" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-opacity="0.65882" stroke-width="0.42366">
      <animate attributeType="auto" attributeName="fill" values="${this.theme.input_bg_color};#00a6ff" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0 0 1 1" dur="0.3s" begin="indefinite" 
      repeatCount="1" additive="replace" accumulate="none" fill="freeze" id="on_switch_color"></animate>
</rect>
```

In my animation I wanted my fill value to be chnaged to a gradient `url(#linearGradient850)` instead of `#00a6ff`.

How do I do that ?

Comment: set the gradient to have the same stop colours i.e. #00a6ff then the gradient will look like a solid colour. On click animate the stops.

Comment: @RobertLongson I know how to animate to a solid color, I want my end color [the poin at which animatin stop] to be a gradient, instead of solid color.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok I got it what you mean. Hmm that is one solution. Do we have another way to make the fill value to be a graident instead of solid color ? Moreover that linear transition of colors will not occur [or i have to write some linear equations to simulate it] for color change.

Comment: have a rect element with the linearGradient behind the rect with the solid fill then decrease the opacity of the solid rect element. It all depends on how you want the transition to look, but you haven't explained what you want.